# Remove "category" from permalink with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'am trying to remove the `category` part from the my category URLs, so that this

```
mydomain/category/knowledge
```

turns into this

```
mydomain/knowledge
```

I want to use add_rewrite_rule on this. Htaccess is not an option, neither is the Yoast SEO plugin.

I tried this, but I just can't get it to work:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Any ideas how this could work?

Comment: It will help you to fix the problem. [https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/)

Comment: Some solution are there check this Documents : https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the plugin. It also uses the add_rewrite_rule function to achieve this. But I guess I just stick to the plugin, it doesn't seem to include any frontend stuff or slow down anything.